# Look at the value in Column A and find that same value in Column B

Tags: excel-formula

```
Column A   
BMCUD         
BMCUT         
02100         
0300          
0500  

Column B
1600
1800
XYXY 
BMCUT
9888
```

I need to write a formula that will look at the value in `Column A` and find that same value in `Column B`.  It should populate `Column C` with the result: `True` if there is a match, otherwise `False`.

Notice that value "BMCUD" does not exist in `Column B`. Therefore, my formula would populate `False`.  "BMCUT" does exist in `Column B`, so it should populate `True`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Match` function was designed for this:

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0)),"False","True")`